# JavaScript : Get values of attributes of an object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm trying to get values of all attributes of an object and I tried using `Object.values()` and I only this in the console :

var a = queryPlan.combo.getFilterMapOfIdToWgt();
        console.log(Object.values(a));

```
[constructor]
```

but it actually contains a lot of values :

```
[constructor]
0:constructor
activeErrorsTpl:(8) ["<tpl if="errors && errors.length">", "<ul class="{listCls}">", "<tpl if="Ext.enableAria">", "<tpl if="fieldLabel"><div>{fieldLabel}</div></tpl>", "</tpl>", "<tpl for="errors"><li>{.}</li></tpl>", "</ul>", "</tpl>"]
activeUI:"default"
autoGenId:true
auxStore:constructor {removed: Array(0), blockLoadCounter: 0, isInitializing: false, initConfig: ƒ, initialConfig: {…}, …}
bindings:[]
bodyEl:constructor {dom: div#hemonth-1050-bodyEl.x-form-item-body.x-form-item-body-default.x-form-text-field-body.x-form-text…, id: "hemonth-1050-bodyEl", el: constructor, initConfig: ƒ, initialConfig: {…}, …}
```

I'm trying to access each of this values. Is it possible to get it and if yes How do I get it? 
Would greatly appreciate your help and thanks in advance.

Comment: sample input please

Comment: How is anybody supposed to help you with how you asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ES6+**

if you use ES6+ you can use `for..of` loop:

```
var myArray = [ 1, 2, 3 ];

for (var v of myArray) {
   console.log( v );
}
// 1
// 2
// 3
```

the `for..of` loop iterates directly over the values of the object's attributes.

**PRE-ES6**

For pre-ES6 you can use the standard `for` loop:

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 3];

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    console.log( myArray[i] );
}
// 1 2 3
```

Comment: `for .. of` is for arrays. For objects, use `for .. in`.

Comment: You're right, but `for..of` also works for objects with a custom iterator.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let obj = {
  key1: 'val1',
  print: (x) => { console.log(x)}
}

for(var attr in obj){
  
 if(typeof obj[attr] == 'function'){
   obj[attr]('123');
  }
  
  if(typeof obj[attr] == 'string'){
   console.log('hi attr is:',attr, 'with value:',obj[attr])
  }
}
```

Without you sharing how is the object looks like, here I'm creating sample object and how you loop thru the attribute and using them. If you wish to have a more specific answer to your question, include them in your question